# GA4 API Python dimension_filter / filter expression wildcard/regexp? Google Analytics Universal Analytics

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Using the GA4 API in Python. I've used their sample call as below. However, in my code below I'm looking for the string 'email', specified in `dimension_filter`.

I'd like to use dimension filter to look for a string that CONTAINS email. Currently it's looking for an exact match. Using a wildcard in SQL, this would be LIKE `'%email%'`.

Can anyone help with this please?

```
#export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "my filepath"


import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'credentials.json'


from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import (
    DateRange,
    Dimension,
    Filter,
    FilterExpression,
    FilterExpressionList,
    Metric,
    RunReportRequest,
)

"""Runs a simple report on a Google Analytics 4 property."""
# TODO(developer): Uncomment this variable and replace with your
#  Google Analytics 4 property ID before running the sample.
property_id = "1234"
# Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
# specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()
request = RunReportRequest(
        property=f"properties/{property_id}",
         dimensions=Dimension(name = "sessionMedium")]
        ,metrics=[Metric(name="transactions")]           
        ,date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="2023-07-03", end_date="2023-07-09")]
        ,dimension_filter=FilterExpression(
            filter=Filter(
                field_name="sessionMedium",
                string_filter=Filter.StringFilter(value ="email"),
            )
        ),
    )
response = client.run_report(request)
#print_run_report_response(response)

print("Report result:")
for row in response.rows:
      #  print(row.dimension_values[0].value, row.metric_values[1].value)
                    )
```

as above, I've not been able to find how to do wildcards with the GA4 API.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use dimension filter to look for a string that CONTAINS email then there is option matchType in StringFilter. You can use that. There is some other matchTypes also there such as EXACT, BEGINS_WITH, ENDS_WITH, FULL_REGEXP and PARTIAL_REGEXP. Bases on your use case, use correct matchType For this code you have to use CONTAINS and edit the code like this:

```
dimension_filter=FilterExpression(
                filter=Filter(
                    field_name="sessionMedium",
                    string_filter=Filter.StringFilter(
                        match_type=Filter.StringFilter.MatchType.CONTAINS,
                        value="email"
                    ),
                )
        ),
```

For more reference: [*FilterExpression*](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/FilterExpression)